# curl stop working on my server

Tags: php, curl

Curl stop working on my server but it is working perfectly on the other server

Here is my script:

```
 <?php
    $proxy_ip = '165.139.149.169'; 
    $proxy_port = '3128';
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=skinny+fiber+ingredients&btnG=Search&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&num=100&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=sw9CVbCuPKaA8QfX0ICYBA&gws_rd=cr';  
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5); // Good leeway for redirections.    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);  
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "abc";
    echo $data;
?>
```

http://serpbull.com/dev/curl.php (script not working here)
http://imarkdev.com/serp/curl.php (script working here)

Edit:
Not working script takes very long to respond (curl timeout) and prints empty response.

Answer (score 0):

Use curl_error() function to get more information about the failure.

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if ($data === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo 'Response: ' . $data;
}
```

Comment: I am getting error : "Curl error: Failed to connect to 165.139.149.169 port 3128: Connection timed out"  any advise on this.

Comment: It means that your webserver can't connect to your proxy server.

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: It is a network issue - access could be restricted by firewall. Why do you need a proxy?

Comment: well I am working on rank tracking tools, to get rank from google. is there nay way I can fix this.

Comment: Try to use curl without proxy settings.